# No module named <FILENAME> when Flask and Pycharm are both in Debug mode

Tags: python, flask, debugging, pycharm

Recently I have updated Pycharm from 2020 to 2022.2.1 version.
In older version, using Flask debug mode

```
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

While debugging with Pycharm used to work.

But after updating, If I want to debug I must use `debug=False` in Flask.

This is very inconvenient as now I must re-run every instance of the application, where before it would rerun the every time a file has been changed.

Attached the error itself, and the run configuration.
This is only related to Flask as running a regular python file in the same directory works.
Any solutions?
I couldn't find anything related to this.
[image: error photo]

[image: config]

Comment: Python bases its module import off of the `PATH` variable that it gets from environment. [Please make sure that it is configured properly.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/absolute-path-variables.html)

Comment: And by properly, I mean add the directory where you have your `dash_crypto_test_strategy` into that list of configured directories.

Comment: I added another screenshot from run configurations, please note that everything is set properly regarding the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on src(sources folder)--?Mark Directory As-->Sources Root